# c++ : template member addition function

Tags: c++, templates, template-classes

I have an interface `IOperand` :

```
class IOperand
{
   public:
     virtual IOperand * operator+(const IOperand &rhs) const = 0;
     virtual std::string const & toString() const = 0;
}
```

And the class `Operand` :

```
template <class T>
class Operand : public IOperand
{
   public:
     virtual IOperand * operator+(const IOperand &rhs) const;
     virtual std::string const & toString() const;
     T    value;
}
```

The `IOperand` class and the members functions `operator+` and `toString` prototype cannot be modified.
The member function operator+ has to add 2 values contained in 2 `IOperand`. My issue is that this value can be an int, a char or a float but I don't know how to do that with templates. I have tried this :

```
template <typename T>
IOperand *              Operand<T>::operator+(const IOperand &rhs) const
{
  Operand<T> *op = new Operand<T>;
  op->value = this->value + rhs.value;
  return op;
}
```

my `toString` method :

```
template <typename T>
std::string const &     Operand<T>::toString() const
{
  static std::string s;  // Provisional, just to avoid a warning for the moment
  std::ostringstream convert;
  convert << this->value;
  s = convert.str();
  return s;
}
```

But the compiler does not find `this->value` and `rhs.value` because they're not in `IOperand`.

EDIT : As advice in the comments, I added the `toString` method in `Operand` and `Ioperand`, I don't really know if it could help.

Comment: Is `class Operand : public Operand` supposed to be `class Operand : public IOperand` ?

Comment: Please do not return pointers: Your operator is a memory leak - get the basics before playing with templates.

Comment: I'm forced to do that, It's a school exercise

Comment: Then you have my sympathy (unless the point of the excercise is to show how *not* to do it) - this is horrible code design.

Comment: @JérémyPouyet you should add the IOperand::toString() method in the question (as defined in the subject), although this is horrible, you can solve your problem with it (rhs.toString() should return a string representation of the T)

Comment: Done. But I only return the number in the Operand as a string, have I to do something else ?

Comment: @JérémyPouyet well you could use the getType() and use streams to convert the value back to the intended type for your operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful word of binary operators. What do you *want* to happen when you do this:

```
IOperand* foo = new Operand<Matrix<Complex>>;
IOperand* bar = new Operand<Polynomial<FiniteField<5>>>;
IOperand* baz = *foo + *bar;
```

?

There are basically two possible answers. You want a compilation error, or you want a runtime error. The latter is easily doable with a dynamic_cast, the former is easily doable by throwing away your design, taking a CS university course, then PhD, then creating your own theory of binary operations and inventing your own OO language.

Of course don't neglect mundane things like memory leaks while doing all that.

Answer (score 3):

If `IOperand` is really untouchable, you'll have to resort to `dynamic_cast`:

```
template <typename T>
IOperand * Operand<T>::operator+(const IOperand &rhs) const
{
  if (const Operand<T> *arg = dynamic_cast<const Operand<T>*>(&rhs))
  {
    Operand<T> *op = new Operand<T>;
    op->value = this->value + arg->value;
    return op;
  }
  else
    return NULL;  // Or any other sensible "error occured"
}
```

The `dynamic_cast` will succeed only if `rhs` is actually an instance of the same `Operand<T>` as the one on which `operator +` is called. This is then checked in the `if`.

However, let me state that this is *horrible* design. Operators should be overloaded to behave as much as the built-in ones as possible (unless you're using them in domain-language style). Using `+` on `std::string`s doesn't result in a pointer to a dynamically allocated `std::string` either.

Code legibility aside, the primary reason why it's so wrong is that it's very easy to leak memory - the only sensible implementation of this `operator+` will allocate memory dynamically, and since it returns a raw pointer, it's left up to the caller to ensure that memory is not leaked. *Bad stuff.*

Comment: @DieterLücking maybe you can explain how to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

define IOperandas template class with typename T

add `T get_value()` in `class IOperand` should work,

overload this function Operand, so you can fetch the data defined in child class

Comment: Seeing as `IOperand` doesn't know anything about `T`, this answer makes little sense as is...

Comment: `Operand` *is already* a template. `IOperand` is not, and per the OP cannot be changed (and making it a template would defeat its purpose anyway).